# My composer.json does not install new dependencies using composer update command

Tags: json, laravel-5, composer-php

I am installing external dependencies using `composer update` command. The following is the section of the `composer.json` file in `c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\` directory.

```
"require": {
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
        "matriphe/imageupload": "5.1.*"
        "illuminate/html": "5.0.*@dev"
},
```

I am getting the following results after running the composer update command:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

I have also tried to create another require array in the composer.json and added the packages I want to install with no success.

The `composer update` command could not install any unstalled dependency using the `composer update` command. Even `composer self-update` did not solve the problem.
Kindly assist me, I have been stuck here for some days now trying all I would do but without success.

I am changing the composer.json under the following directory: c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\     Is this ok?

Comment: Running composer install also returns Nothing to install or Update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't change any files inside the `vendor` directory, they are managed by Composer. To install further packages use the `composer.json` in your project's directory.

And use `composer install` to install new packages as `composer update` will update already installed packages to newer versions (if available) too.

`composer self-update` just updates Composer itself.

Comment: I am changing the composer.json under the following directory: c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\     Is this ok?

Comment: No you need to change `c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\composer.json`. NEVER change something inside the `/vendor/` folder.

Comment: its like adding the packages to wrong composer.json file. Thank you Peh for your assistance. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You missed column after `"matriphe/imageupload": "5.1.*"`, try to change it:

```
"require": {
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
        "matriphe/imageupload": "5.1.*",
        "illuminate/html": "5.0.*@dev"
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I am getting the same results even after updating to this code: "require": {
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
        "matriphe/imageupload": "5.1.*",
        "illuminate/html": "5.0.*@dev"
}